# Duplicate some information from database and change with meeting id?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel project. I can basically do CRUD operations about meetings. So i want to add duplicate meeting button that duplicates the meeting with unique meeting id. I created new get route `"admin/duplicate/meeting/{meeting}"` and i created duplicate_meeting method in my AdminController. Finally added a button on my blade templates and gave the route. But when i click the button it shows me 404. Here is my web.php file:

```
    Route::get('/admin/meeting/history', [AdminController::class, 'meetingHistory'])->name('admin.meeting.history');
    Route::get('/admin/meeting/add', [AdminController::class, 'meeting_add'])->name('admin.meeting_add');
    Route::post('/admin/meeting/add', [AdminController::class, 'do_meeting_add'])->name('admin.do_meeting_add');
    Route::get('/admin/meeting/edit/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'meeting_edit'])->name('admin.meeting_edit');
    Route::post('/admin/meeting/edit', [AdminController::class, 'do_meeting_edit'])->name('admin.do_meeting_edit');
    Route::get('/admin/meeting/delete/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'meeting_delete'])->name('admin.meeting_delete');
    Route::get('/admin/meeting/duplicate/{meeting}', AdminController::class,'meeting_duplicate')->name('admin.meeting_duplicate');
```

And AdminController.php:

```
 public function meeting_duplicate(Meeting $meeting)
    {
        $newMeeting = $meeting->replicate();
        $newMeeting->meeting_id = uniqid(); // Generate a unique meeting ID
        $newMeeting->created_by = auth()->user()->name; // Set the creator of the new meeting to the current user
        $newMeeting->created_by_mail = auth()->user()->email; // Set the creator's email of the new meeting to the current user
        $newMeeting->joined = 1; // Set the joined status to 1
        $newMeeting->save();

        // Redirect to the newly duplicated meeting
        return redirect()->route('admin.meeting')->withSuccess('Meeting duplicated successfully.');
    }
```

Finally my meeting.blade.php:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/admin/meeting/duplicate/{{ $meeting->meeting_id }}">Duplicate Meeting</a>
```

Can you help me about this issue?

EDIT: There is a method called do_meeting_add in my AdminController:

```
public function do_meeting_add(Request $request)
    {

        $settings = Settings::first();
        $request->validate([
            'title' => ['required', 'min:3'],
            'meeting_id' => [
                'required',
                'regex:/^\S*$/u',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($request, $settings) {
                    $meeting_id = $settings->meeting_id . $value;
                    if (Meeting::where('meeting_id', $meeting_id)->exists()) {
                        $fail('The Meeting ID has already been taken.');
                    }
                },
            ],
        ]);

        $microphone = false;
        if ($request->checkbox == '1')
        {
            $microphone = true;
        }
        $desktop = false;
        if ($request->desktop == '1')
        {
            $desktop = true;
        }
        $user = Auth::user()->name;
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        $notification = NotificationSettings::first();
        $file_name = '';
        if ($request->hasFile('waiting_logo')) {
            $file = $request->file('waiting_logo');
            $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = $file->storeAs('img/uploads', $file_name, ['disk' => 'public_uploads']);

            $photo = Image::make(public_path("{$path}"))->resize(275, 275);
            $photo->save();
        }

        $waiting_video = '';
        if ($request->waiting_video !== '') {
            $waiting_video = $request->waiting_video;
        }

        $waiting_title = '';
        if ($request->waiting_title !== '') {
            $waiting_title = $request->waiting_title;
        }

        $waiting_description = '';
        if ($request->waiting_description !== '') {
            $waiting_description = $request->waiting_description;
        }
        if ($request->password)
        {
            Meeting::create([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'meeting_id' => $settings->meeting_id.$request->meeting_id,
                'created_by' => $user,
                'created_by_mail' => $email,
                'password' => $request->password,
                'app_id' => $notification->app_id,
                'microphone' => $microphone,
                'desktop' => $desktop,
                'logo' => $file_name,
                'video_embed' => $waiting_video,
                'waiting_title' => $waiting_title,
                'waiting_description' => $waiting_description
            ]);
        }else{
            Meeting::create([
                'title' => $request->title,
                'meeting_id' => $settings->meeting_id.$request->meeting_id,
                'created_by' => $user,
                'created_by_mail' => $email,
                'app_id' => $notification->app_id,
                'microphone' => $microphone,
                'desktop' => $desktop,
                'logo' => $file_name,
                'video_embed' => $waiting_video,
                'waiting_title' => $waiting_title,
                'waiting_description' => $waiting_description
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('You have added this meeting successfully!');
    }
```

So how can i create duplicate_meeting function in a right way?

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the route.

```
Route::get('/admin/meeting/duplicate/{meeting}', AdminController::class,'meeting_duplicate')->name('admin.meeting_duplicate');
```

Here you're missing open and closed brackets. So, it should be:

```
Route::get('/admin/meeting/duplicate/{meeting}', [AdminController::class,'meeting_duplicate'])->name('admin.meeting_duplicate');
```

EDIT:
Also, I'd suggest not to Name your Methods this way. It won't cause any issue but it's not a standard to have special characters in Function names. Instead of using "_" you can use "CamelCase".

This way your method name would be: "meetingDuplicate" instead of "meeting_duplicate"

Comment: ups, yeah i forgot about that but sadly, still getting an 404. But thanks for the advicing.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for 404 error might be from another route that is above your duplicate route. Something like:

```
Route::get('/admin/meeting/{meeting}', ....
```

Check if you have a route like this (not exactly, but as a pattern), if so, move this line:

```
Route::get('/admin/meeting/duplicate/{meeting}', [AdminController::class,'meeting_duplicate'])->name('admin.meeting_duplicate');
```

above that line.

Comment: i tried it but still i get 404 error. I think there is a problem with my method called meeting_duplicate in AdminController class.

Comment: maybe should i do post request due to get request because i dont have any blade template for duplicate meeting because when i click duplicate meeting i want to redirect to meetings route again to see the duplicated meeting in table. I dont want to add a specific page for duplicate meeting etc.

Comment: I think the problem does not related to post-get method.
The main problem is reaching the path.
Can you add the whole route file content